# Why more than one file created when converting csv to parquet using aws glue?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am converting a csv file to parquet and store it to s3 location, but when i check the location i be getting more than one file instead of one file?

Answer (score 0):

By Default, Spark/Glue writes data in parallel in order to optimise writing. You may enforce to write to one file by using `coalesce()` method before write.